# Upgrade PostgreSQL from 9.6 to 10.0 on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

My database is over 600 GB and my current volume is only 1 TB, so that probably limits my options.

My config files are here:

```
/etc/postgresql/9.6/main
```

My database is here:

```
/mnt/1TB/postgresql/9.6/main
```

Edit  -
This guide worked for me. The only addition I needed to make was to download libicu55 manually and install it, and I had to grant postgres 1777 permission for my /tmp/ folder. I was also saving the data folder to a different drive, so I had to use the command:

```
pg_upgradecluster -m upgrade 10 main /mnt/1TB/postgresql/10
```

https://gist.github.com/delameko/bd3aa2a54a15c50c723f0eef8f583a44

Comment: "*will logical replication work with Postgresql 10 on an Ubuntu server towards a Windows 10 machine with Postgresql 10*" - yes.

Comment: After you installed the Postgres 10 binaries you can migrated the current data directory to Postgres 10 using `pg_upgrade`. If you use the `--link` option only minimal additional space is required during the upgrade.

Comment: But: don't forget to make a backup, first. Preferably to a different medium (or machine)

Comment: My server is 16.10, will this link for 16.04 work fine? deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ yakkety-pgdg main

Comment: postgresql-10 : Depends: libicu55 (>= 55.1-1~) but it is not installable is the error I got using the yakkety codename. Is it safe to use the 16.04 codename in the .list file?

Comment: Awesome. I am all set. SELECT version() shows I am running 10.0. Kind of a headache but not too bad. I will drop the old cluster tomorrow.

Answer (score 270, accepted):

### A Step-by-Step Guide

1. **Make a backup**. Make sure that your database is not being updated.

   ```
    pg_dumpall > outputfile
   ```
2. **Install Postgres 10**. Follow instructions on this page: https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/

   Then run `sudo apt-get install postgresql-10`. A newer version will be installed side-by-side with the earlier version.
3. Run `pg_lsclusters`:

   ```
    Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory               Log file
    9.6 main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.6-main.log
    10  main    5433 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/10/main  /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-10-main.log
   ```

   There already is a cluster `main` for 10 (since this is created by default on package installation). This is done so that a fresh installation works out of the box without the need to create a cluster first, but of course it clashes when you try to upgrade `9.6/main` when `10/main` also exists. The recommended procedure is to remove the 10 cluster with `pg_dropcluster` and then upgrade with `pg_upgradecluster`.
4. Stop the 10 cluster and drop it:

   ```
    sudo pg_dropcluster 10 main --stop
   ```
5. Stop all processes and services writing to the database. Stop the database:

   ```
    sudo systemctl stop postgresql
   ```
6. Upgrade the 9.6 cluster:

   ```
    sudo pg_upgradecluster -m upgrade 9.6 main
   ```
7. Start PostgreSQL again

   ```
    sudo systemctl start postgresql
   ```
8. Run `pg_lsclusters` . Your 9.6 cluster should now be "down", and the 10 cluster should be online at `5432`:

   ```
    Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory               Log file
    9.6 main    5433 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.6-main.log
    10  main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/10/main  /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-10-main.log
   ```
9. **First, check that everything works fine.** After that, remove the 9.6 cluster:

   ```
     sudo pg_dropcluster 9.6 main --stop
   ```

#### Some notes on `pg_upgradecluster`

This guide works fine for upgrading from 9.5 to 10.1. When upgrading from an older version, consider omitting `-m upgrade` on the step #6:

```
sudo pg_upgradecluster 9.6 main
```

If you have a really big cluster, you may use `pg_upgradecluster` with a `--link` option, so that the upgrade will be in-place. However, this is dangerous — you can lose the cluster in an event of failure. Just don't use this option if not necessary, as `-m upgrade` is already fast enough.

Based on:

- Docs: [Upgrading a PostgreSQL Cluster](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/upgrading.html)
- Gist #1: [delameko/upgrade-postgres-9.5-to-9.6.md](https://gist.github.com/delameko/bd3aa2a54a15c50c723f0eef8f583a44)
- Gist #2: [johanndt/upgrade-postgres-9.3-to-9.5.md](https://gist.github.com/johanndt/6436bfad28c86b28f794)
- [What happens if I interrupt or cancel `pg_upgradecluster`?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/173382/what-happens-if-i-interrupt-or-cancel-pg-upgradecluster/173400)
- [Ubuntu manpage for pg_upgradecluster](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/pg_upgradecluster.8.html)

#### Update

This guide works fine for upgrading from 9.6 to 11 and from 10 to 11, as well as from 10 to 13.

Comment: First command I had to change to  sudo -u postgres pg_dumpall > outfile

Comment: Great job on this guide, it worked perfectly going from 9.3 to 10.0. Thanks!

Comment: This tutorial works successfully for upgrade 9.4 to 10 in debian "buster/sid". In my case, the `pg_dumpall > outfile` command had to be ran as `postgres` user.

Comment: Just upgraded from 9.6 to 10 using this on ubuntu 16.04, wonderful, thank you

Comment: After step #6, I have to run "sudo systemctl start postgresql" to bring the new version (10) online.

Comment: After doing last `pg_lsclusters` it shows both clusters as down. However postgresql 10 is installed and on service start it starts successfully. Also verified `pg_dump --version` and `pg_restore --version`
Earlier version was 9.5 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: For anyone curious, these steps also work great for PostgreSQL 9.6 -> 11.

Comment: Very informative answer. I just had to do "sudo systemctl start postgresql " in the end. Rest all worked like a charm. I didn't realise upgrading DB can be so painless.

Comment: i used `--link` additional flag because not enough disk space and it's really2 fast, also backuping first using ``time pg_dumpall | xz -1v > database.`date +"%Y.%m.%d"`.pgdumpall.xz``, and of course `byobu` to prevent ssh disconnection

Comment: To avoid performance regression, remember to run analyze after the upgrade. Read the output.

Comment: failed for me (or one using postgis) at the #6 step because of:

`could not load library "$libdir/postgis-2.2": ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.2": No such file or directory
could not load library "$libdir/rtpostgis-2.2": ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/rtpostgis-2.2": No such file or directory`

postgis was changed from 2.2 to 2.4 and upgrade script is not able to handle that.

Comment: This works flawlessly but it returns an error when trying to upgrade from 9.5 to 11 let's say if you have postgis installed. As @Alexander Vasiljev mentioned the error. is there a proper way to handle this? or a workaround?

Comment: @M03 complete dump (#1) and then complete restore in new DB

Comment: I see a pg_dump to backup the all the databases but i don't see a point where the databases are restored...so what happens to the backed up data?

Comment: @herbertichama `pg_dumpall` is just a safety measure. The dump is needed only if something goes wrong.

Comment: @MaxMalyshIReinstateMonica, splendit..this has worked flawlessly. I had never done this for postgres databases.Everything just worked smoothly

Comment: i had issues with 'unknown' column types in the 9.6; first upgrade try failed because of the same and then in the second trial, changed the column type into text (that column had only string values) and then did the upgrade - which went successful. Thanks a lot for the details steps and write up!

Comment: in the end, the upgraded cluster didn't start, even after reboot. I ran `sudo pg_ctlcluster 10 main start` to start it

Comment: Upgrade from 9.5 to 13.3 worked out well following these instructions.
I just needed to specify the password for the pg_upgradecluster command with `sudo PGPASSWORD=<password> pg_upgradecluster -m upgrade <old-version> main`. Without it, the command failed with `fe_sendauth: no password supplied`.

Answer (score 0):

Almost worked out of the box. I'm on 17.10 artful. While you *can* put that in the .deb file, it wont work - Postgres only update the non LTS releases if they break the LTS release. So put Zesty into that deb and you are good to go.