# Postgres 10 Upgrade Stuck Queries

Tags: postgresql, upgrade

I followed these instructions:

[Upgrade PostgreSQL from 9.6 to 10.0 on Ubuntu 16.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46687645/upgrade-postgresql-from-9-6-to-10-0-on-ubuntu-16-10)

And got the upgrade done without issue. I kept the old cluster - however with identical queries on the new cluster im getting:

- wait_event_type: IO
- wait_event: DataFileRead

These queries that hang are largish in that they join 10's millions of rows. I have double checked postgresql.conf and parameters where present in both the 9.6 version and 10 version are identical except:

"bytea_output"
"client_encoding"
"hot_standby"
"max_connections"
"max_replication_slots"
"password_encryption"
"port"
"server_version"
"server_version_num"
"superuser_reserved_connections"
"wal_level"

I have both clusters up on the same machine - tables I'm querying are sitting on the same tablespaces, queries are identical, config is more or less identical - is there something I'm missing with postgres 10?

Many Thanks

Comment: I hope,they are not: `are sitting on the same tablespaces,...` If you used pg_upgrade, did you run the `analyze_new_cluster.sh` script?

Comment: Thank you for your reply - when I say same tablespace I mean same names sitting on the same disks (as in I haven't changed the data locations). I also ran the analyze script which did not change anything. I have both clusters running so I guess its time to dig and dig