# Upgrade Postgresql from 9.6 to 11 with different data directory

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to upgrade PostgreSQL version from 9.6 to 11. I am following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47233300/1357214). The problem is I have changed my default location of PostgreSQL data directory from `/var/lib/postgresql/` to `/opt/postgresql/`. So when I am using `pg_lsclusters` it is returning following

[image]

When I am running the `sudo pg_upgradecluster -m upgrade 9.6 main` its returning following error

```
Error: move_conffile: required configuration file /var/lib/postgresql/11/main/postgresql.conf does not exist
Error: Could not create target cluster
```

Comment: This question is better suited for https://serverfault.com/ as it is unrelated to programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you moved the folder *before* running `pg_upgradecluster` so now it can no longer find the config file.

If you already have a backup, I would do the following:

- Move `/opt/postgresql/9.6/main` **back** to where it was before (in `/var/lib/postgresql`)
- (unsure about this one): Remove `/opt/postgresql/11/main`
- Run `pg_upgradecluster 9.6 main /opt/postgresql/11`
  This will tell it to use the default location of `9.6/main` and store the upgraded version into `/opt/postgresql/11`

I am unsure about the second point as I don't remember how `pg_upgradecluster` deals with existing folders. But as long as you keep a backup, you can play around with it. My best guess is that it will exit with an error if it sees that the folder already exists to ensure nothing is overwritten. So you may need to delete it.

You could try to move the folder back to the old location and then run `pg_upgradecluster` again. But you have to be careful: The version 9.6 to 11 is a major upgrade which changes the on-disk binary format. `pg_upgradecluster` should take care of this by making a dump/load operation.

### If the above fails

Here are some pointers to get you going:

- `pg_upgradecluster` does nothing more than a dump/load but with a more convenient CLI interface
- You can manually start a cluster using `postgres -D </path/to/postgres/9.6/main> -c </path/to/9.6/main/postgresql.conf> -p <port>`
- Once manually started, you can run `pg_dumpall --cluster 9.6/main -Ft -f dump.tar`
- Run `pg_createcluster -d /opt/postgresql --start 11 main` (using `--start` will start it up after creation).
- Once this is started, you should be able to reload the previous dump into that cluster. You should be able to target that new cluster using `pg_restore --cluster 11/main -Ft -f dump.tar` for your dump/load needs

Comment: I already run with datadir `pg_upgradecluster 9.6 main /opt/postgresql/11`. It was running fine. But stopped due to new error. `Error: pg_upgrade run failed. Logfiles are in /var/log/postgresql/pg_upgradecluster-9.6-11-main.FqiK`. In the text file I saw it is unable to load library postgis-2.3, rtpostgis-2.3, libpgrouting-2.4, libpgrouting-2.6 & postgis_topology-2.3.

Comment: I also can not back to `/var/lib/postgresql` as there is no available space to copy huge DB.

Comment: `postgis` is not part of the default installation of `postgres`. Are you sure you installed it for v11?

Comment: I've added some more tips. Not sure how helpful they will be, but they should give you some additional information to recover from your current predicament.

Comment: Just changed the dump-format to `tar` (using `-Ft`) which should be marginally better than using plain SQL output. I have not tested this though. I was not sure if `-Fc` would work as this is a major upgrade.

Comment: I am trying to get the points of this tutorial https://www.bostongis.com/blog/index.php?/archives/268-Using-pg_upgrade-to-upgrade-PostGIS-without-installing-an-older-version-of-PostGIS.html

Comment: That article looks dodgy. Playing around with `.so` or `.dll` files is often risky business and should only be done if you *really* have no other option.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200173/discussion-between-exhuma-and-devils-dream).